# How to open files contained in a folder in current file path

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a file (`file`) that is stored in a folder (`Source`) which is in the same directory as the current workbook. I get a runtime error 1004 indicating that it the file can't be located. What am I doing worng?

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\file*.xlsx")
```

Comment: Remove the * in the filename

Comment: @SBF That works but I would like to keep the wildcard as the file name is not always exactly the same.

Comment: How will you open the correct file when there are multiple files matching the file* ? You need exact filename or a file selection dialog .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the wildcard to stay, you need to loop through the files in the folder. Something like this may be of interest to you:

```
Sub FileOpen()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\"
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "file*.xlsx")

    ' Loops while there is a next file found in the specified directory
    ' When there is no next file the Dir() returns an empty string ""
    Do While sFile <> ""

        ' Prints the full path of the found file
        Debug.Print sPath & sFile

        ' Opens the currently found file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)

        ' Place your code here
        ' Place your code here
        ' Place your code here

        ' Close the current workbook and move on to the next
        wb.Close

        ' This line calls the Dir() function again to get the next file
        sFile = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Thanks what I was trying to do.

Comment: Hi, sorry to ping you here out of nowhere, but please stop suggesting edits that add the [tag:excel-vba] tag to VBA questions. Please click that link and read the tag wiki. Every single one of your edits has been later undone.

Comment: I think you are quite wrong, I read the discussion about [excel-vba] tag's removal and it is suggested to keep all the posts with both [excel][vba] for the future and [excel-vba] until it isn't removed.

It's just natural - if the topic is about Excel and VBA, why would we exclude some tags? Since [excel-vba] has not been removed it is still an existing tag!
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos the tag isn't going to be nuked, that's not how things work. Old posts that have the tag get to keep it (to avoid massively bumping old posts to the home page, and new posts SHOULD NOT USE THAT TAG) Please stop suggesting edits that add the tag, every single top user in the VBA tag is actively removing [tag:excel-vba] whenever they come across it. Next step is a moderator flag and an edit-ban. The tag wiki EXPLICITLY states to use [excel][vba] INSTEAD.

Comment: You'll notice every single post (those I checked anyway) you added it to, has later been edited to remove it (by various users) - making most of your +2 reps borderline fraudulent. Also it can't be done the way your 6yo could do, because it would flood the font page with a bajillion VBA posts and nobody wants that.

Comment: Alright, fine! I'm not gonna debate this with you :D I'm quite sure that since this is a site run by programmers somebody could surely figure out a way to edit the tags without updating the posts so they would not move to the front page. :') Perhaps nobody is really interested! Good talk. Take care

Answer (score 0):

Replace the wildcard with actual filename.

Comment: That works but I would like to keep the wildcard as the file name is not always exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set x = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source\file.xlsx"

I changed the file*.xlsx to file. xlsx...hope your code works.

thanks.

Comment: That works but I would like to keep the wildcard as the file name is not always exactly the same.

Comment: ok. that looks like there is lot more code to be written to check for wildcard inside the VBA and get the name of the exact match, store it in a variable and then open it. I think you need to add more code to what you have already written.