# Excel-VBA Loop not looping through all files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have below does a loop through the excel workbooks in the folder I selected, but for some reason it is skipping a random file each time I run the code. For instance, I have 8 files in the folder I selected--it is only performing the copy paste task I have in the code on 7 of the files. It is also not looping in order--for instance it is looping through the 3rd file first and then the 5th file 2nd... etc..HALP

```
'Retrieve Target Folder Path 'Opens folder picker and prompts user to navigate to current month's templates location   Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode 'If OK is selected
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assigns selected folder to myPath
    End With
     'If user does not select folder and hits Cancel NextCode:   myPath = myPath   If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension   myExtension = "*.xls*"

'DIR function gets first file name in the folder  'with appropriate file
     myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension) 'Loop through each excel file in folder until DIR 'cannot find anymore

Do While myFile <> ""
    'Opens the file and assigns to wb variable for future use
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Copy the balance worksheet(Sheet2)from each workbook 
    'in the specified folder and paste to master
      For Each wb In Workbooks
         If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
             'Copy entire worksheet
                wb.Worksheets(2).Cells.Copy
             'PasteSpecial Values Only   
                wb.Worksheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears Clipboard
            'Copy the values pasted in workbook
            'and paste to the Master file
               wb.Worksheets(2).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            'Set the name of the newly pasted values
            'in the master file to the name of the workbook the values were copied from
             ActiveSheet.Name = wb.Name
        End If
      Next   Set wb = Nothing   'Close Workbook
    Workbooks(myFile).Close SaveChanges:=False      'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents   'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed      MsgBox "Task Complete!"

End Sub
```

It should loop through all files in folder and it is not. The file it is skipping is sporadic each time I run the code.

Comment: "ActiveSheet.Name = wb.Name" What should this line really do? I may be wrong, but I think you cannot change ActiveSheet.Name - you can only do this by activating another sheet.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546337/how-to-open-files-contained-in-a-folder-in-current-file-path. I've used a similar code plenty of times to loop through Workbooks in one folder or even multiple folders with sub-folders and it always worked - also what you pointed out, this code loops through in an order.

Comment: `myExtension` is commented out so I doubt `myFile` is what you expect.  You use `GoTo NextCode` but I do not see that `Label`, what actually happens when user clicks `Cancel`?   How are `Next   Set wb = Nothing ` and `myFile = Dir Loop` not throwing an error?